# Python Selenium get cell value based on coordinates

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

**I want to find a specific cell in a table based on coordinates.**

HTML

```html
<div id="model" class="mobile handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" data-originalstyle="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="ht_master handsontable"><div class="wtHolder" style="position: relative; height: 380px; width: 1468px;">
  <div class="wtHider" style="width: 2550px; height: 2109px;">
    <div class="wtSpreader" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <table class="htCore">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="rowHeader" style="width: 50px;">
          <col style="width: 400px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader cornerHeader">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class=""> 
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">Division, Base Alternative</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2015 (M)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2016 (N)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2017 (O)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2018 (P)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2019 (Q)</span>
              </div>
            </th>
           </tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>                                                                                                     <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">1</span>
                </div>
                </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
            <tr>
              <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">2</span>
                </div>
               </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
            <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="rowHeader">3</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Model period</td>
            <td class="afterHiddenColumn htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          </tr>         
        <tr>
          <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
            <div class="relative">
              <span class="rowHeader">7</span>
            </div>
           </th>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, pulp mill, MUSD</td>
          <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">597</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">572</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">648</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">35</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
          <div class="relative">
            <span class="rowHeader">8</span>
          </div>
         </th>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, paper mill, MUSD</td>
        <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
```

> Picture of the original grid table
> [image]

> I have tried a bunch of different methods, but I can't understand how to do it.

> I want to find a cell, based on `line 7` & column name `2017 (O)` for example, and get
> its value

> The only example I find, is to find a cell by its index or by its value, that's not what I want to accomplish.

*Thanks in advance!*

*EDIT*
I have provided more HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath to get the position of the column index based on header text.

```
count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]/preceding-sibling::th)
```

You might need to adjust position based on structure like

```
count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
```

Use following function to get the dynamic value based on the row number and cell header you want.

```
def Get_Cellvalue(rownum, colheader):
   element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[{}]//td[count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]/preceding-sibling::th)]".format(rownum,colheader))
   print(element.text)

Get_Cellvalue(7,"2017 (O)") 
Get_Cellvalue(7,"2018 (P)")  
Get_Cellvalue(7,"2019 (Q)")
```

Hope this will solved your task.

Comment: I'm still getting all cell values from that row, I want to get a specific cell with the coordinates in somehow.

Comment: @Herker :  The Html you have provided is in correct I have used xpath based on assumption. Please provide valid html and your expected out from that.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look!  sorry for the unclear code

Comment: @Herker : It is very hard to understand data based on screenshot. I would request you to please post data in text format you can copy entire html and make anonymous data if security issue and then provide expected data you want. If html is two large you can sort it with 2-3 records just to know how the structure look like.

Comment: I have updated my question & provided more HTML code.

Comment: @Herker : Check the updated answer and let me know how this goes?

Comment: THANK YOU!  It almost works, getting the wrong cell values but that's close enough. But I think I know the reason. Depending on what index the cell is located, it takes that index * 2 + 1. I have uploaded a picture of the original table in my question. If I want to access cell with 7, 2017 (O) which has an index of 2. Then I get a cell that has an index of 5. Any ideas?

Comment: @Herker : Are you getting wrong column index? then check with this. using add or substruct `td[count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]/preceding-sibling::th) +1]` or   `td[count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]/preceding-sibling::th) -1] ` or +2 or -2 in that way.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but the index variates from cell to cell. The question is how to solve this as generic as possible.

Comment: @Herker : I need more info about HTML to check if I can manage not to break. I appreciate If you post a new question and provide more details of the HTML I can give a try.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
OUTPUT:
241
672

"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# this var contains html table
bs4 = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html", 'r').read(), "html.parser")


def get_cell(row: int, col: int) -> str:
    tb = bs4.find('tbody')
    # this variable contains the desired row
    row = tb.find_all('tr')[row]
    # this variable contains the desired cell
    cell = row.find_all('td')[col]

    return cell.text

# the function get_cell takes a row number and a column number
print(get_cell(0, 1))
print(get_cell(0, 2))
```

Comment: But would rather if it's possible to just use Selenium to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work:

```
"""
OUTPUT:
241
672

"""

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# get to some url
driver.get()

def get_cell(row: int, col: int) -> str:
    # this var contains a tbody tag of table
    tb = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody')
    # this variable contains the desired row
    row = tb.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[row]
    # this variable contains the desired cell
    cell = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[col]

    return cell.text

# the function get_cell takes a row number and a column number
print(get_cell(0, 1))
print(get_cell(0, 2))
```

Comment: I get --- "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'"